# What connector standard is used for aviation headsets?

Tags: radio-communications, cockpit, avionics

The typical aviation headset features two cords with connectors that at first glance are identical. One is a standard 1/4" (0.25 inch) stereo audio jack.

What kind of connector is the slightly smaller, slightly narrower one?

Comment: Does [this](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/2900/1696) answer your question?

Comment: Totally OT, I know, but I just had a vision of a pilot bopping down the street with his DCs plugged into his phone (via a ¼" to 3.5mm adapter), jammin' to some tunes. Would put those kids with their wimpy Beats™ to shame!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's for the microphone (the standard sized one is for the head phones). They are different size so the pilot knows to try the other hole if it doesn't fit.

From [wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_%28audio%29#Aircraft_headsets)

> Commercial and general aviation (GA) civil airplane headset plugs are
>   similar, but not identical. A standard 1⁄4 in monaural plug, type
>   PJ-055, is used for headphones, paired with special tip-ring-sleeve,
>   0.206 inch diameter plug, type PJ-068, for the microphone. On the microphone plug the Ring is used for the microphone 'hot' and the
>   sleeve is common or microphone 'Lo'.