# What is the name or part number of the Bose 'Lemo' aviation headset connector?

Tags: radio-communications, radio, headset

In a similar direction to [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11992/what-connector-standard-is-used-for-aviation-headsets) question, I was wondering if anyone knows the name or part number of the connector commonly featured on Bose aviation headsets such as the A20. It is commonly know as the 'Bose connector', 'lemo connector' or the '6-pin connector'.

The A20 [manual](https://assets.bose.com/content/dam/Bose_DAM/Web/consumer_electronics/global/products/headphones/a20_aviation_headset/pdf/746706_og_a20_en.pdf) merely calls it the `6 pin plug` (page 13) and gives the connector dimensions (page 35).
The name 'lemo' suggests it's one of the connectors developed by the LEMO company (perhaps something from the B or K series?).

Comment: Aircraft Spruce sells the [Bose 6 pin LEMO installation kit](http://www.aircraftspruce.com/catalog/avpages/bosexaccess8.php?clickkey=10792).  Have you tried calling their tech support for more info?

Answer (score 7):

The connector on the end of the headset's cable is a P-Series. Specifically it is PN [PAG.M0.6NL.AC65NZ](https://www.lemo.com/pdf/PAG.M0.6NL.AC65N.pdf). You will need to purchase the [strain relief](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/232/unipole_multipole-973098.pdf) separately. If you are looking for the socket Then you need PN [PRG.M0.6NL.LC65N](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/LEMO/PRGM06NLLC65N?qs=mDYDupiwM4Dx1CuDVSmm7Q%3D%3D) for inline connections or [PTG.M0.6NL.LC65N](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/lemo/PTG.M0.6NL.LC65N/1124-1224-ND/2786326) for Panel connections.

Unless you own or want to buy the crimp tool, you will need buy solder contacts (and buy extras if you've never soldered these before.) In my experience, universal crimpers don't work well enough with LEMO parts. If you are doing panel mount consider how important FAA compliance is in your situation and consider paying an avionics guy or consulting a DAR (or whichever governing body and official is salient to you.)

UPDATE: On closer reading of [the P series catalog](https://www.lemo.com/catalog/ROW/UK_English/P_series_catalog.pdf), the first letter of the last sequence determines whether the connectors are crimp or solder. A and L indicate male and female solder, respectively. C and M represent male and female crimp. The part numbers provided above are, therefore all for solder connection.

[image: Contact Configuration Chart]

Note that it is possible Bose had a special variant made for them. In most cases this means special keying to make the connector proprietary. It is possible file keys off of generic connectors but that is not really recommended. I disclaim any responsibility if you waste $23 or have an uncomfortable conversation with your FSDO or DAR. Note also that these parts can be a bit hard to research because they are actually made by Redel, a subsidiary of LEMO. Calling these things LEMO connectors is a bit like calling a Porsche 911 a Volkswagen 911.

I've included links to digikey and mouser in my references. Either site is a great source for parts in the US and should stock all the parts I've referenced.

Additionally, here is the [P-series catalog](https://www.lemo.com/catalog/ROW/UK_English/P_series_catalog.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

The connector mentioned on [Sporty's](http://www.sportys.com/pilotshop/aviation-headsets/bose-aviation-headsets/6-pin-connector-to-twin-plug-adapter-for-bose-a20-aircraft-powered-headsets.html) is called:

> 6-pin LEMO Connector to GA Twin Plug Adapter (for Bose A20 Aircraft Powered Headsets)

The part number or product ID is 1643A. I'm not sure if that is Sporty's ID or LEMO as I could not find this connector on LEMO's product page.

[image]
<sub>*[Image Source](http://www.sportys.com/media/catalog/product/1/6/1643.jpg)*</sub>